# How to change columns rather then row numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel

If I in one cell had C2:C32, when I drag the average down in a different column, how do I stop it going to C3:C33, C4:C34 ect and go D2:D32, E2:E32?

Comment: you question is not clear

Answer (score 1):

Replace $A$1 with the actual cell you're starting from

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET($C$2,0,ROW()-ROW($A$1),31))
```

Uses `row()` in combination with `offset()` to increment the column offset as the formula is filled down. Keep in mind that `offset()` is volatile, meaning the entire formula will recalculate whenever you make a change anywhere in your workbook.